# OctoPack nuget push

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am trying to set up teamcity with octopus deploy following the tutorial in here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/851282/CI-CD-using-GIT-Team-City-Octopus

I think the tutorial is using teamcity version 9.x and i am using 10.x . I am using visual studio 2015. my octopack is 3.5.2.

I set up a sample application in Github called `ToDoWebApp.sln`

I set the configuration in octopus deploy and add Build Step for Visual Studio (sln)

inside the Visual Studio (sln), I check the `Run Octopack` tickbox.

I tried to run the build and it keeps coming with this error:

> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\packages\OctoPack.3.5.2\build\OctoPack.targets(109, 5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\packages\OctoPack.3.5.2\build\nuget.exe" push "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f091ac5edf11aa03\TodoWebApp\obj\octopacked\TodoWebApp.25.nupkg" MyApiKey -Source je"

I tried to run the command directly on the command prompt and it complains that `je is invalid source.`

how do i know what is the url for `je` in teamcity?

if i want to test it in the command prompt, what should I replace `je` with? my teamcity is in localhost:90 . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 'source' option is the NuGet repository URL, so for Octopus you have to put the URL of the inbuilt NuGet manager (e.g. http://octopus.example.com/nuget/packages)